# the difference of functions tends to zero

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions

If for any $\epsilon >0$,there exists $a_0$(depends on $\epsilon$) such that $f(a_0)>1-\epsilon$,where $f$ is a real function.We also know  that $f(a_0)\leq 1$,can we deduce that $f(a_0)^4=f(a_0)$?

My thought:$1\geq f(a_0)\geq f(a_0)^4 >(1-\epsilon)^4$,then$ |f(a_0)-f(a_0)^4|<1-(1-\epsilon)^4$,the right side of the inequality tends to zero.

Is it correct?

Comment: Just a quick thought: If $a_0$ is a function of $\epsilon$, the above becomes an inequity relation that has to be solved, and might not have an answer. Is something like $f(x)=\tanh(x)$ a counterexample?

Comment: If $f(a_0)=a_0$,can we conclude that $a_0=a_0^4$?

Answer (score 1):

Let a = a$_0$, r = $\epsilon$.  As a is dependent
upon r, nothing can be concluded about f(a).

For example, let r = 1.  All that is possible
is that exists a with 1 >= f(a) > 0.
Pick a different r, you get a different a with different results,
If r approaches 0, then at each step there is a different a.
When claiming f(a) = f(a)$^4$, what a do you mean?

If a is a constant, it is easy to prove f(a) = 1.

Comment: Does $|f(a_{\epsilon})-f(a_{\epsilon})^4|$ tend to zero?

Comment: Likely, but to what does $a_r$ tend?